# Unable to cast anonymous object to System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I use to linq to sql to fill a gridview:

```
var results = from r in db.MyForm1_hosps
                      where r.recordId == recordId
                      orderby r.hospId
                      select new { r.hospId, r.which, r.description };

        if (results.Count() > 0)
        {
            Form_1_hosp.DataSource = results;
            Form_1_hosp.DataBind();
        }
```

later during OnRowDataBound, i call the following code to fill in the value of a radiobuttonlist

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            RadioButtonList rbl = e.Row.FindControl("which") as RadioButtonList;
            if (rbl != null)
            {
                DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)(e.Row.DataItem);
                LoadRadioButtonList(rowView["which"], rbl);
            }
        }
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`3[System.Int32,System.Int16,System.String]' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.
```

I understand that an anonymous object cannot be cast to a datarowview, but what can I cast to in order to get the value of "which"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define a proper class to describe your data, and then you will be able to cast to this class.

```
// replace with proper names and types, as appropriate 
class MyData 
{
     public int HospId { get; set; }
     public string Which { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Update your query's `select` to utilize this class for the projection

```
select new MyData
{
    HospId = r.hospId, 
    Which = r.which, 
    Description = r.description 
};
```

And then use the type for the cast.

```
MyData obj = (MyData)(e.Row.DataItem); 
LoadRadioButtonList(obj.Which, rbl);
```

There are other techniques for dealing with this, such as using `dynamic` and letting the runtime figure it out, or using a `CastByExample<T>` method (you can look it up, but I consider it faily hack-ish), but this is in my opinion the cleanest thing to do.

---

You could arguably also simply omit the projection and use the full object

```
select r;
```

At which point you would simply cast to the type of the elements in `db.MyForm1_hosps`, which is presumably `MyForm1_hosp` (you would have to verify). The counter against this approach would be if your UI container is auto-generating columns *and* this class contains more data than you wish to display, in which case, you would want to continue with the projection into a smaller construct.

Comment: this looks good. i wont be able to try this until monday and will mark as answered if it works (which it should).

Comment: both worked. I went with the second as I have 5 gridviews and didn't want to create 5 classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anthony's answer worked perfectly for me as well, though I'm doing things slightly differently.  My goal is to display information related to tax filings and electronic funds transfers.

I'm using a RadioButtonList in an ItemTemplate.  Each added item has it's own value ("Y" or "N") which corresponds to the string stored in the database.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="TableHeader"  HeaderText="Pay Estimate by EFT?" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoPayEstbyEFT"  runat="server">
             <asp:ListItem Value="Y">Yes</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="N">No</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:RadioButtonList>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

I created a class called EFT to define all the data I'm retrieving in my LINQ to SQL statement

```
public class EFT
{   
    public int JUR_ID {get; set;}
    public string JUR_NAME {get; set;}
    public DateTime FYE {get; set;}
    public int STATE {get; set;}
    public string ENT_NAME { get; set; }
    public string ENT_ABBREV { get; set; }
    public string TYPE_NAME { get; set; }
    public int RETURN_ID { get; set; }
    public string EFT_EST { get; set; }
    public string EFT_EXT { get; set; }
    public string EFT_RETURN { get; set; }
}
```

then modified the LINQ to SQL to select a new instance of that class (jurisdictions, entity, taxtypes, and returns all reference joins that are not displayed here).

```
select new  EFT {JUR_ID = jurisdictions.ID, JUR_NAME = jurisdictions.NAME, FYE = jurisdictions.FYE.Value , STATE = jurisdictions.STATE.Value , ENT_NAME = (entity.NAME.Contains(",") ? entity.NAME.Substring(0, entity.NAME.IndexOf(",") -1).ToString() : entity.NAME ), ENT_ABBREV = entity.ABBREV, TYPE_NAME = taxtypes.TYPE, RETURN_ID = returns.RETURN_ID.Value, EFT_EST = returns.EFT_EST, EFT_EXT = returns.EFT_EXT, EFT_RETURN = returns.EFT_RETURN }
                                     ).ToList();
```

Then in my RowDataBound I'm extracting the "Y" or "N" value from the database and assigning that string to the selected value.

```
RadioButtonList rdoPayEstbyEFT = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rdoPayEstbyEFT");

EFT rowView = (EFT)e.Row.DataItem;
string strESTbyEFT = rowView.EFT_EST.ToString();
rdoPayEstbyEFT.SelectedValue = strESTbyEFT;
```

Works like a charm!